# Solving $\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} x^{\frac{3}{2}} (1-2x)^{\frac{3}{2}}dx$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, definite-integrals

How to solve the definite integral $\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} x^{\frac{3}{2}} (1-2x)^{\frac{3}{2}}~dx$?

Funnily enough, this is actually a problem that showed up during my real analysis course. At first glance, the problem seemed solvable by using knowledge from basic elementary calculus, but it turned out not to be so simple. I initially tried the substitution $u=\sqrt{x}$, but that lead me nowhere...

> Let $u=x^{\frac{1}{2}}$, $du=\frac{1}{2}x^{-\frac{1}{2}}$.
>
> $\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} x^{\frac{3}{2}} (1-2x)^{\frac{3}{2}}~dx$ = 
>   $2\int_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} u^4 (1-2u^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}~du$.

EDIT: I have tried an additional substitution to the above, namely $u= \frac{\sin t}{\sqrt{2}}$.
$$
\begin{align*}
2\int_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} u^4 (1-2u^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}~du&=
2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin^4 t}{4} (1-\sin^2 t)^{\frac{3}{2}}\cdot \frac{\cos t}{\sqrt{2}}~dt\\
&=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^4t\cos^4t~dt.
\end{align*}
$$
Hopefully my calculations aren't wrong...

Comment: I'm working on a solution using your u-substitution, but it will take a bit

Comment: Let $y=2x$ and use the [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function), or write $\sin2t=2\sin t\cos t$ and employ [Wallis' integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals).

Comment: @Lucian Thank you so much for that tip! The reductions for the trig functions were way too tedious, using the beta function made things much simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} x^{\frac{3}{2}} (1-2x)^{\frac{3}{2}}dx$$
Substitute $u = \sqrt{x}$
$$ = 2\int_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} u^4 (1-2u^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}dx$$
Substitute u = $\frac{\sin(s)}{\sqrt{2}}$, $du = \frac{\cos(s)}{\sqrt{2}}$ (this will be valid for $0 < s < \frac{\pi}{2}$)
$$ = \sqrt{2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{4}\sin^4(s)\cos(s)cos^2(s)^{3/2}ds$$
$$ = \sqrt{2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{4}\sin^4(s)\cos^4(s)ds$$
$$ = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin^4(s)\cos^4(s)ds$$
We then apply the following reduction formula with $m=4$ and $n=4$ (which is really messy... I'll leave out a lot of intermediate stuff): 
$$\int \cos^m(s)\sin^m(s)ds = -\frac{\cos^{m+1}(s)\sin^{m+1}(s)}{m+n} + \frac{n-1}{m+n}\int \cos^m(s) \sin^{n-2}(s)ds$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{3}{16\sqrt{2}}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin^2(s)\cos^4(s)ds$$
$$=\frac{3}{16\sqrt{2}}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (1-\cos^2(s))\cos^4(s)ds$$
$$=\frac{3}{16\sqrt{2}}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \big(\cos^4(s) - \cos^6(s)\big)ds$$
$$=\frac{3}{16\sqrt{2}}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^4(s)ds - \frac{3}{16\sqrt{2}}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^6(s)ds$$
We then apply the following reduction formula for $m=6$:
$$\int \cos^m(s) = \frac{\sin(s)\cos^{m-1}(s)}{m} + \frac{m-1}{m}\int \cos^{m-2}(s)ds$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{1}{32\sqrt{2}}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^4(s)ds$$
Apply the cosine reduction formula again for $m=4$:
$$\Rightarrow \frac{3}{128\sqrt{2}}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^2(s)ds$$
We then make the substitution $cos^2(s) = \frac{1}{2}\cos(2s)+\frac{1}{2}$, and after a few very basic calculus and algebra steps arrive at the solution.
$$= \frac{3\pi}{512\sqrt{2}}$$

Comment: Let it be noted... Typing out this method sucked. It works though, and is based off of your initial substitution (showing that your gut feeling was right, $u= \sqrt{2}$ will work.... it just takes a LOT of additional steps). This is not even close to the simplest way to work this out by hand though, so let that also be noted ;)

Answer (score 4):

Note that there $x$ and $(\frac 12 - x)$ is symmetric about $x= \frac 14$. Thus try to substitute $y = \frac 14 -x$. Then the integral is

$$- \int_{\frac{1}{4}}^{-\frac 14} (\frac 14 -y)^\frac{3}{2} (\frac 12 + 2y)^{\frac 32} dy = 2^{\frac 32} \int_{-\frac 14}^{\frac 14} (\frac 1{16} - y^2)^{\frac 32} dy.$$

From here one can use trigonometric substitution.